# Is CQ5 used as a backend service?

Tags: aem

I have experience with other enterprise CMS's like Teamsite & Tridion, but no hands on experience with CQ5. I'm wondering, how is CQ5 usually integrated with a large site that has content & functionality?  Functionality defined as pages are generated with data from a non-CMS repository or webservice.

My question is, is CQ5 content  read in as a back-end service?  I know the API is http based.  But is that API typically called from server or client?   For my example, lets say I have a page that is from mostly driven from a web service that is linked to some non-CMS enterprise system, but I want the footer & right rail to be "content" so that the users can change it easily. At what point would the the different page sources typically be combined?

I'm wondering because I work with asp.net.  I know the CQ5 is Java, so I would expect that most cusomters are java shops, but I would think that the HTTP would be easy to consume for an ASP.net site, if it is really just another backend webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really not all that clear to me to be honest. So I'm going to answer this rather broad.

To answer your question about the different page sources:
The client usually initiates a http or json request to the server (although server to server calls are not uncommon in case of extended infrastructure) and the server simply executes the necessary calls (using the apis) and delivers the answer to the request. But at the point of request return, all calls to the api have been made by the server, and the server is just returning rendered html or json, or whatever structured form you want to have your data and/or content in.
A page consists of various components. Some components are fairly static. Others are very dynamic and pull their data for example from a webservice, or external database or even another cms. The combining of these resources happens upon the rendering of the page which in its turn was triggered by a request for that page. The obvious exception is ofcourse the dispatcher caching system which will return a cached version of the page if possible. But in short, all the rendering and api calls are made server side.

CQ5 is fairly flexible since it's split up into 2 instances. The backend (author) which is where the actual authoring of pages happens. And the frontend (publish) which is basically the frontend, and does the actual rendering for a client (usually).
Wether you choose to use the publish instance a backend service is just up to you to be honest. I've seen cq5 used as what it was ment for (cq5 being the frontend), and I've seen cq5 used as a backend service (for example: as a backend service provider for hybris). And I've seen the combination, where one part was used as backend service for another system, and the other part was used for a public website frontend.

Comment: You answered my question.  People are using CQ5 as a backend service.  Do you know of many CQ5 customers accessing CQ5 as a backend content store for a an ASP.net site?

Comment: I've never seen it done with an ASP.net site, but I don't doubt that there are companies with an asp site who tied in cq5 for some parts of their site. I've only seen it done with a couple of jsp sites, but the principles remain the same. Make an http call to the cq5 page(s) and parse the xml or json in the application

Answer (score 1):

CQ's rich HTTP API (based on [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/)) gives full access to the CQ content in various formats including JSON and XML, so integrating CQ content in other systems is easy.

In the other direction, you can use Sling's ResourceProvider mechanism to access external content and make it part of the CQ content tree. See "custom resource providers" in the Sling Resources docs at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html .